# AD B2C compareClaims throws internal server error

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am trying to compare 2 claim (one from id_token_hint and one from AD B2C) . My requirement is to throw an Error Page that the 2 do not match and re-direct to login page.

For the same I have added the following steps :

1. Added ClaimType (boolean for comparison)

   ```
   <ClaimType Id="agencyClaimMatch">
   <DisplayName>Verify if input Agency and agency in AD B2C match</DisplayName>
   <DataType>boolean</DataType>
   <UserHelpText>Verify if input Agency and agency in AD B2C match</UserHelpText>
   </ClaimType>
   ```
2. Create a ClaimTransformation (based on [post](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/issue-with-claimequals-in-azure-ad-b2c-3554c4546a6) to compare the 2 claims (extension_agency from AD B2C and agency from input claim of id_token_hint)

   ```
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="checkSameAgency" TransformationMethod="CompareClaims">
     <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_agency" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim1"/>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="agency" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim2"/>
     </InputClaims>
     <InputParameters>
       <InputParameter Id="operator" DataType="string" Value="EQUAL"/>
       <InputParameter Id="ignoreCase" DataType="string" Value="true"/>
     </InputParameters>
     <OutputClaims>
       <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="agencyClaimMatch" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim"/>
     </OutputClaims>
   ```

3.Added a Technical Profile to invoke the transformation (I am expecting the agencyClaimMatch boolean to get a true or false value based on the transformation, if false bot do not match need to throw the error page else allow access)

```
        <TechnicalProfile Id="CheckAgencyMatch">
       <DisplayName>Check Agency Match</DisplayName>
       <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
       <Metadata>
          <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
       </Metadata>
       <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
       <InputClaims>
         <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="agency" Required="true" />
         <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_agency" Required="true" />
       </InputClaims>
       <OutputClaims>
         <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="agency"/>
         <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_agency" />
         <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="agencyClaimMatch"/>
       </OutputClaims>

      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
         <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="checkSameAgency"/>
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

4. In UserJourney I added a ClaimExchange to get the value of checkSameAgency.

   ```
        <!--Verify claims match and get the boolean value-->
    <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="CheckAgencyMatch" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="CheckAgencyMatch"/>
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
   ```
5. If boolean output checkSameAgency is not "True" that is both agencies do not match then throw an error else move to next step to issue jwt token .

   ```
    <!-- Check if agencID Match-->
    <OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
          <Value>agencyClaimMatch</Value>
          <Value>True</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAssertedAgencyNotMatched" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAssertedAgencyNotMatched" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
   ```

But I am getting an error "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred." even if the agency matches or if they don't.

Comment: As suggested by @rbrayb updated from <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />

A SelfAssertedAttributeProvider is only used to display a screen, but you are only comparing claims. It should be
<Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claims-transformation-technical-profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="CheckAgencyMatch">
           <DisplayName>Check Agency Match</DisplayName>
           <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
           <Metadata>
```

A SelfAssertedAttributeProvider is only used to display a screen, but you are only comparing claims. It should be

```
<Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
```

Refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claims-transformation-technical-profile).